# Android scaleType aspectFill

Tags: android

What is the value for `android:scaleType` that will achieve the effect of **scale aspect fill**? In other words, I need the image to keep it's aspect ratio, but it should fill the canvas. This will obviously lead to part of the image being cut off (if canvas and image aren't similar rectangles) but I want it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). `CENTER_CROP` seems to be what you're looking for:

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Answer (score 0):

The value you appear to want is 'CENTER_CROP'.

Answer (score 0):

Center_crop is what you're searching for. This property will expand the image until fill the container, preserving in center and ratio.

Answer (score -1):

```
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```